# php includes inside other includes

Tags: php

So my login check I have split into two sections that I tried putting in two different files and including them. First I will show the original code then the split code. I think my problem is with the link to the include. I try to use an absolute path. But it seems to be failing. My whole App is modular so I have global files set up outside of the rest of the App structure and I call the files as needed. I have also thought of just loading the functions through _autoload() but I don't know that this would solve my issue.

```
<?
//Inventory index.php
include$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Globals/db_connect.php';
include$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Globals/functions.php';
sec_session_start();if(login_check($mysqli)==true){?>

/////Html and or more php code to be executed. Usualy a mix of both.

<?}else{
echo ("You are not authorized to access this page, please <a href=\"http://website.com/AUTH/login.html\">login</a>. <br/>");}?>
```

here is what I am trying to do....P.S. I know my code is kinda hard to read I am trying to format it for easier reading but I can process clumps better than I can spaced code. Not sure why.

```
<?
//Inventory index.php
include$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Globals/auth1.php';?>

/////Html and or more php code to be executed. Usualy a mix of both.

<?}else{include$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Globals/auth2.php';?>
```

What I think is happening is the includes in Auth1 are failing. are my absolute paths failing? Am I better off using _autoload().

Comment: why don't you use `include ('Globals/auth1.php');`?

Comment: You will always be better of using `__autoload()` but for that you need to use classes.

Comment: You're better off indenting, and properly formatting your code for starters, and you're better off _not_ using the short opening tag, too.

Comment: There is no space between include and $ don't know if this is in your code or only here... You can try to replace the $_server by the real path to see if it works, then you know where your issue is coming from. +1 to what Elias said

Comment: @Micallef This index is located in www/apps/invetory/index.php the auth1 is in www/globals.auth1.php I need to access the globals directory. not from the /inventory directory but from the /www directory. this is how i keep the code that is standardized across the app separate from the code that changes per app. basically this is my own custom CMS with apps seprate from the rest of the CMS. but functions need to be called from the CMS for the apps to interface properly. I may do a little more research and go the _autoload() route like Mihai Said.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem formating that doesn't affect execution is kinda not a big deal to me. I can process clumps better that having to scroll through a page of code. My mind seems to prefer it that way. I understand that for others to read it they need it to be formated properly I understand the sentiment. As I said, I am sorry its not formated for optimal reading.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. But @MihaiStancu pretty much answered the questing by letting me know it would be a better decision to go the _autoload() route.

Comment: @user3221147: If you ever want to make a living writing code, you'll have to come to terms with the fact that proper formatting is _very_ important. There's a reason why all sizable projects define, among other things, a coding style. The short opening tags business, though, is just bad practice: they're not enabled by default. Avoid code that requires specific server setup stuff...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I will take your advice and learn to format the code properly then. I don't make a living writing code but would like to someday. Thank you for the wisdom.

Comment: The ability to visually follow code based on structure and formatting is an "acquired taste". If you'll work on a project with a certain standard for a long enough time you'll get used to it (which ever one it may be) and all others will look less readable (until you work with them for a while).

Comment: Check out the [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for autoloading standards. They will help you structure your code into files and folders and keep compatibility with other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always choose "autoloading" in favor of manual includes for multiple reasons.

1. Readable structure -- one class for each file and one folder for each namespace segment allows you to find anything in the directory structure of your project very fast.
2. Easy maintenance -- if you change the folder structure/position of your files (as well as their namespaces) you're done, no paths to be rewritten and verified.
3. Compatibility with other projects for example using [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) or [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). PSR-0 is meant for covering legacy code, **PSR-4** *should* be used for new libraries.
4. Compatibility with package management software -- which expect some kind of predictable conventions to be respected. For example [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/) expects either PSR-0 or PSR-4 and it enables autoloads for you.

On the subject of coding standards and formatting the same applies:

1. familiar structures are easier to recognize.
2. The decision is perfectly arbitrary; it's always your (or your team') choice. Either will work fine -- you will get used to any one of them.
3. Consistence is important, [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) are the lingua franca of both Symfony & friends as well as  many other projects which use composer as their package management (and others).

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use composer and it's [autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) which support different types of files loading. For production you can use [--optimize option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) to make autoloading works better (as I remember composer scan all folders and build array of existing files)